# Is there any way to make ODBC connection be in the Class?

Tags: vb.net

I tried to make my ODBC Connection within the class.
here's my class code

```
Public Class Library

    Public Function Seek(ByVal Connection As Odbc.OdbcConnection, ByVal TableName As String, ByVal Field As String, ByVal Index As Long)
        Dim LibDS As New DataSet
        Dim LibDA As Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter = New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " & TableName & " WHERE " & Field & " = " & Index & "", Connection)

        Return LibDA.Fill(LibDS, TableName)
    End Function
End Class
```

...and here's my form's code.

```
    Dim LibDS1 As New DataSet

    LIbDS1 = Table.Seek(LibConn, "tblRoles", "UserID", varUserID.UserID)
    If LibDS1.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Role").ToString = "member" Then
        MsgBox("You are member")
    End If
```

Here's my error: **Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Data.DataSet'.** I am using VBdotNet2005

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function returns `Integer` value but you want to return the DataSet.

```
Public Function Seek(ByVal Connection As Odbc.OdbcConnection, 
           ByVal TableName As String, ByVal Field As String, ByVal Index As Long) 
                      as DataSet
  .....
  LibDA.Fill(LibDS, TableName)
  Return LibDs
End Function
```

Comment: @aerohn - Return value of Fill() method is integer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure about this without seeing more of your code (specifically any imports, etc.) - but my guess is that `Table.Seek` is returning an integer (Int32) - which can't be assigned to a `DataSet`.  You can't get a `DataSet` from the result of `Table.Seek`.